# Vim reopen current file into read-only?

Tags: vim

I have searched through couple of places but wasn't able to find any answer. The title states it all, is there a command to close the current file and re-open it right away in read-only mode?

Comment: What's wrong with `:set ro`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

say your file is `hello.sh` which you opened in vim with

```
vim hello.sh
```

now to close and open it in read-only, press `ESC` and type

```
:view!
```